# IntelliJ CE macOS suggestion menu in code editor doesn't stay open

Tags: intellij-idea

For 2 or 3 weeks, I don't remember if it appeared after an upgrade, the suggestion menu that comes after a dot while editing code, to inspect methods and props, no longer remains open. It appears less than 1 sec then close.

I removed all my prefs and get a fresh copy. Same issue.

It's a bit boring to code.

Comment: Does the issue persist in https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ with the default settings (File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...: https://i.imgur.com/kbrkC7w.png)?

Comment: Yes. It's solved with the "nextversion" and the Restore to Factory. Thanks a lot

Comment: With the update of IdeaUAP, it request a registration. I'm learning Kotlin so it's a bit expensive for me. I downloaded the new IdeaC but the problem remain. Do you know if there is a fix in preferences?

Comment: You can download IntelliJ IDEA Community EAP.

Comment: ohh. Thanks. I didn't even see the gray button just under the blue one. :-|